# AWS Lambda function Restriction

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, lambda, gateway, subnet

I have a Lambda function exposed as an API via API Gateway. How can I make sure that the Lambda function is called only by the API Gateway and it cannot be called by any other means i.e. bypassing the API gateway. In my scenario the API gateway and the Lambda function are sitting in the default system managed VPC. The Lambda function is configured to internally accesses the resources from some of the private subnets of my VPC.

How do I make sure that the Lambda function cannot be called by bypassing the API gateway. Please help...

Abhijit

Comment: Lambda functions don't work correctly on public subnets, and there's no reason to provision them there... so either your Lambda function is not really on a public subnet or you haven't yet encountered any of the capabilities that do not work in that configuration... such as most of the AWS SDK.  API Gateway is not on any subnet of your VPC at all.  API Gateway is on public networks that are not connected to your VPC, and the communication between API Gateway and Lambda does not traverse your VPC at all.  You may want to review your configuration and/or clarify the question.

Comment: My mistake in saying above that Lambda function sits in the Public Subnet. What I mean is that it is sitting in the default system managed VPC. What I really want to restrict is - stopping somebody with valid credentials to call the Lambda through CLI or other means. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only allow API Gateway to Invoke the Lambda. This can be done via IAM permissions. This link has info about configuring IAM for API Gateway to invoke your Lambda. Only allow this permission and nothing else will be able to invoke the Lambda.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html